# Fading in and out Ajax search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am currently using Ultimate WP Query Search Filter plugin in Wordpress. I am trying to get my Ajax search results to fade in and out when the user selects various options.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".content").hide();
    })
.ajaxStop(function() {
    $(".content").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

This works successfully when the user initially searches and there is no content, it fades in smoothly. However if search results are on the screen and the user chooses a new option, the content is hidden without an effect. Is it possible to fade out the existing content when a new option is selected?

If I set the ajaxStart to fade out the content gets displayed without an effect and then fades in and then out.

Comment: `$(".content").fadeOut();` are you looking for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `fadeOut()` callback function to kick off the ajax after the `fadeOut` animation ends.

```
$(".content").fadeOut(1500,function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart().ajaxStop(function() {
        $(".content").fadeIn(1500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the element is already visible, like:

```
if($(".content").is(':visible')) {
    $(".content").hide();
}
```

and then show fadeIn with the new content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
  $(".content").show(1500);
});
```